# Loading a non-MVC intranet webpage in MVC View

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have an old custom asp intranet site in which we access our internal databases and I've managed to setup a html page to be able to load other intranet sites like ccnet, wiki etc using <iframe /> tags, via the static menu on top of the page.

Example legacy code:

Menu.asp:

```
<body topmargin="0" and leftmargin="0">
<div id="header">
     <a href="default.asp" id="logo">
     <img src="Images/Home.png" alt="Bam! Home" width="40" height="40"/>
     </a>
     <ul id="NavMenu">
          <li><a>DB tasks</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=RestoreBak">Restore .bak</a></li>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=RestoreSqb">Restore .sqb</a></li>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=CreateDbSnapshot">Create Snapshot</a></li>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=RevertToDbSnapshot">Revert to Snapshot</a></li>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=DeleteDbSnapshot">Delete Snapshot</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a>General</a>
                <ul>
                     <li><a href="ccnet.asp?Target=Wiki">Wiki</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

ccnet.asp (to load the intranet page in an iframe to retain the menu):

```
<!-- #include file = "common.asp" -->

<html>

<head>
     <title><%

'Common DB tasks:
     if Request("Target") = "CreateDbSnapshot" then
          Response.write "Create Db Snapshot"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RevertToDbSnapshot" then
          Response.write "Revert To Db Snapshot"

     elseif Request("Target") = "DeleteDbSnapshot" then
          Response.write "Delete Db Snapshot"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RestoreBak" then
          Response.write "Restore Bak"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RestoreSqb" then
          Response.write "Restore Sqb"

'General
     elseif Request("Target") = "Wiki" then
          Response.write "Wiki"

'Final just incase there is an unavailable option:
     else
          response.write "DBServer CCNet"
     end if
     %></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common.css"/>
</head>

<!--#include file ="menu.asp"-->
<body>
     <%

     dim iFrameTargetSrc
'Common DB tasks:
     if Request("Target") = "CreateDbSnapshot" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/server/local/project/1.%20Create%20DB%20Snapshot/ViewProjectReport.aspx"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RevertToDbSnapshot" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/server/local/project/3.%20Delete%20DB%20Snapshot/ViewProjectReport.aspx"

     elseif Request("Target") = "DeleteDbSnapshot" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/server/local/project/FS%20Backup%20SQB/ViewProjectReport.aspx"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RestoreBak" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/server/local/project/Restore%20DB/ViewProjectReport.aspx"

     elseif Request("Target") = "RestoreSqb" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/server/local/project/Restore%20SQB/ViewProjectReport.aspx"

'General
     elseif Request("Target") = "Wiki" then
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://wiki/sites/CompanyWiki/SitePages/newhome.aspx"

'Final just incase there is an unavailable option:
     else
          iFrameTargetSrc = "http://DBServer/ccnet/ViewFarmReport.aspx"
          response.write "Cannot find requested target " & Request("Target") & "."
     end if

     %>
     <iframe src="<%response.write iFrameTargetSrc%>" seamless="true" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="94%"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

We've started to convert this legacy intranet site to MVC5, but what I can't figure out is how to be able to create a view that can load the ccnet and other intranet site pages in a view which spans the whole page when selecting the link from the menu. Views need the data from the controller. How should I pass the information to the controller and load the view containing the non-mvc intranet site?

I'm trying to add the menu option to the _Layout.cshtml page, but haven't found anything that can point me in the right direction of how to implement this.

Any advice, containing a link that can show me how by using examples or solutions posted here will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an action method to a controller like this

```
public ActionResult LoadExternalSystem(string identifier)
{
  switch (identifier.ToLower())
  {
    case "wiki":
    {
      ViewBag.LoadUrl = "http://wiki.somewhere";
      break;
    }
    case "othersystem":
      {
        ViewBag.LoadUrl = "http://othersystem";
        break;
      }
  }
  return View();

}
```

Then create a view for that action that looks like the following

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoadExternalSystem";
 }

 <iframe src="@ViewBag.LoadUrl"></iframe>
```

Then use the following for your menu

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="@Url.Action("LoadExternalSystem",new {identifier="wiki"})">wiki</a></li>
  <li><a href="@Url.Action("LoadExternalSystem",new   {identifier="othersystem"})">Other system</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The page seems to contain the iframe, but not the src link.
    <iframe seamless="true" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="94%"></iframe>

Comment: Ok, i got it to work by changing the menu to the following:
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Wiki", "LoadExternalSystem", "Home", new { identifier = "Wiki" }, null)</li>
I only need to modify the size of the iframe which is a bit too small.